# Email Notification not delivered to customers in Magento

Tags: magento-1.9, email

I am new to Magento. As an admin i am getting email notifications on orders. But customer doesn't get any email notification on orders, password reset, etc. Is there any settings to be enabled it for customers?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Finally i traced the problem. Its just because of the version 1.9.1. It queues the mails to cron. I just commented the queue syntax in email template. Now It started working. You can refer [Magento 1.9.1 Email Queue not working/buggy - how to troubleshoot and what is considered the best patch?](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46063/magento-1-9-1-email-queue-not-working-buggy-how-to-troubleshoot-and-what-is-co).

But this is just a workaround. The right way is of course to enable the Magento cronjob

in shell (SSH):

```
$ crontab -e
```

Add this line to execute the Magento cron queue every 5 minutes:

```
*/5 * * * *  php /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php -mdefault
*/5 * * * *  php /absolute/path/to/magento/cron.php -malways
```

You might need to replace `php` with the absolute path to your php-cli binary. Ask your hoster if it doesn't work and you don't know the path.

Answer (score 1):

Use this free extension to set up SMTP on your store. Recommended by most people.
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

There may be several reasons why your mail is not getting sent. Maybe you are working on localhost. Or your server doesn't allow sending mails. Checking if mail() function is working would be a good start.

Answer (score 1):

It sounds like there may be some misconfiguration with your server.

I agree with Hashid that you should consider the SMTP Pro Email extension by Ashley Schroder: http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/smtp-pro-email-free-custom-smtp-email.html

Besides that, I highly recommend you to consider pairing Mandrill with the SMTP extension: http://www.mandrill.com/

Mandrill is a transactional email provider and you will improve your email delivery rate if you use their service instead of your own server's mail service.

The first 12,000 emails for Mandrill is FREE every month so you don't have to pay a thing if you are not sending more than 12,000 emails to your customers every month.

**UPDATE (JULY 28, 2016):** Mandrill stopped offering their free service but there are still other providers offering similar service, like SendGrid and Mailgun.

Comment: Unfortunately, Mandrill has stopped this free service.

Comment: Yes, that is correct but there are a few other providers offering this including SendGrid and Mailgun.

Comment: I would suggest Sparkpost if you were using Mandrill for free. Sparkpost offers 100k emails per month for free.