# Aoe scheduler crashed?

Tags: ce-1.9.1.0

I am using magento ce 1.9.1 and the latest version of aoe scheduler (v0.4.3) from https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/tags, because the version from here:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html isn't the latest.

But for a few days the timeline view seems to be crashed and looking weird:

[image]

The list view is just working, only the timeline view looking weird. I tried to reinstall again and again and flushed all caches too, but without an effect.

Any suggestions to fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if you got this fixed yet but I had the same issue myself.
I seem to have resolved it by deleting some very old tasks I found at the very bottom of the List View that seemed to be stuck in the Running state.

Comment: this works really well, thx :)

Answer (score 3):

AOE_Scheduler [reads](https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/blob/master/app/code/community/Aoe/Scheduler/Model/Observer.php#L280) right out of the `core_cron` table for anything that is in process or completed, and also builds out future jobs by processing the `config.xml` of all modules. Since 1.9.1 is fairly new and this is a new feature it may also just not be supported yet. May not hurt to open an issue:

- https://github.com/AOEpeople/Aoe_Scheduler/issues

Noticing the scheduled task name `core_email_queue_send_all` others are [reporting issues](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46063/magento-1-9-1-email-queue-not-working-buggy-how-to-troubleshoot-and-what-is-co#comment64025_46063) with it as well.

Comment: ok, thanks :). I already contacted the developer of this extension, but I can also open an issue.

Comment: I'm running EE 1.14.2.1 which should be the same platform as CE 1.9.2.1 and have only ever had trouble if there's been legacy data in the cron tables. Might even pay to clear them out before you turn on the scheduler.