# Magento after upgrading order update email sending duplicate emails

Tags: php, orders, email

After upgrading to magento 1.9.0.1 from 1.6 order update email is ending 7 times, i had set "Send Order Comments Email Copy Method" to "Seperate Email" and added 7 email ids in "Send Order Comment Email Copy To" field.i dont have any idea to trouble shoot this problem.Can any one suggest how to trouble shoot the problem

Answer (score 1):

If you're receiving the email 7 times to the same email address even though you've specified 7 different emails in the field then check to see how you have them delimited. Make sure you have separated the addresses with commas.

Comment: Thanks for your reply every email address is seperated with ,and these 7 email address are receiving 7 emails

Answer (score 0):

This issue could be related to the new Magento Email Queue system, that leaves orphan records on the Recipients table.

If this is your issue, I've sent a fix on this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87299/23057

Answer (score 0):

You have to use Bcc rather than sending a copy, as there is a bug in the Magento code that just duplicates the recipients.