# Magento sending too many order email copies

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

I just upgraded to Magento CE 1.9.1 from 1.6.2 and we're having issues with the sales order emails now.

In system > config >sales order emails > order > send order email copy to, we have two emails set.

Magento sends an order confirmation email to the customer, and two to each of the emails we have in the send order email copy box. If we put three emails, magento sends three emails to those addresses.

This appears to be the same issue in this thread.
[Magento after upgrading order update email sending duplicate emails](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/55498/magento-after-upgrading-order-update-email-sending-duplicate-emails)

Does anybody have any idea what the issue could be?

Thank you

Comment: More info: I am using Send order email copy method Separate email. I just tested using Bcc and it sends the order email to customer, but none at all to admins.

Answer (score 2):

This issue could be related to the new Magento Email Queue system, that leaves orphan records on the Recipients table.

If this is your issue, I've sent a fix on this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87299/23057