# Order confirmation email sent multiple time - same order confirmation sent to all - unable to stop sending

Tags: email

I am using Magento Enterprise 1.9.1.0.

After creating two client account to run tests, I placed two order, one for each client.
An order confirmation for the first order is sent to both client 61 times per hour since then.
I tried removing all mention of the sending sales@ email address from the configuration panel and disabling  email sending from config. Both the server and the template support indicate that it stems from a bug in Magento.

How can I :
1. Stop the flow of email
2. Ensure proper functioning of automated order confirmation sending

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be related to the new Magento Email Queue system, that leaves orphan records on the Recipients table.

If this is your issue, I've sent a fix on this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87299/23057

Answer (score 0):

In the backend there's an option to turn off all mail sending:

System > Configuration > System > Mail Sending settings

Set "Disable Email Communications" to "Yes". This and:

System > Configuration > Design > HTML Head > "Display Demo Store Notice"

is what I try to do with every new test / development install. Now, why your mail is not being marked as sent, is difficult to say. Judging from the code, a field "processed_at" should be NOT NULL for a message to be considered as sent. This is done by `Mage_Core_Mode_Email_Queue::send()`.

If an exception is thrown, then processed_at never gets set. I can only assume that your mailer returns a non-transient error code.