# Duplicate Order Confirmation eMails

Tags: order-email, order-duplication

I have the problem that I receive order confirmation eMail twice. One is to the copy email I have in noted in the magento backend and one is also to that email and to the customer. So I keep receiving the order confirmation copy twice. 
I cant find the problem or if I remove the order copy from the backend I don't receive anything, when I add it back again, I receive it twice again.

Anybody ever had the same problem and a solution?

Comment: I have same problem did you find hot fix it ?

Comment: @Stasevi4 try changing the email address to something different. Preferably something like a gmail email address to see if the issue persists

Answer (score 1):

This issue could be related to the new Magento Email Queue system, that leaves orphan records on the Recipients table.

If this is your issue, I've sent a fix on this post: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/87299/23057

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. In my case the problem was caused by the source code of the **cron.sh** script.

Maybe my hint helps.

My hosting provider uses his own versions of the **cron.sh** and **cron.php** scripts for the Magento cron-job.

When i changed from the **cron.sh** script to the **cron.php** script for starting the Magento-Cron-Job the new order eMail was only sent once, my problem was solved.

Maybe your issue has something to do with the code of the **cron.sh** or **cron.php** script.

I 've already posted my answer [New order email being sent twice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice/154150)

Answer (score 1):

I have trouble with same issue. Did you downgrade your website? After downgrade our website M2 to magento 1.9, we'd faced this same issue.

You have to look `send()` and `sendEmailqueue()` method.
If `sendEmailqueueu()` method is in `send()`, you delete it. Then, it works.