# Order confirmation email being sent twice

Tags: magento-1.9, order-email

I have no clue about what's going on.

I have a production server and a local dev server, both have the same data, same source code, same running cronjob.

Every time I order something on the production server, the order confirmation email will be sent twice, with the same content. But it works properly on the dev server.

Is there any possible issue that links to this problem based on your experience?

Any response will be highly appreciated.

Comment: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice check this

Comment: You are using any BCC SEPARATE Mail

Comment: @Manashvibirla: I followed both answers but none of them worked for me

Comment: can you take a look in that post ? http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice
Hope it helps