# Duplicate and Previous Customer Transaction Emails are being Sent 1.9.4

Tags: magento-1.9, email, order-email

I apologize if this is the wrong way to ask this question.  I don't have enough reputation points to ask in the original post. And I'm almost out of hair from trying to figure out this issue.

Magento 1.9.4

I'm still having the issue after following the SQL fix provided by César Revert-Gomar.
[New order email being sent twice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice/87299#87299)

I did notice that he mentioned

> The core_email_queue table is cleaned out as emails on the Magento
>   Email Queue are sent. This cleaning is performed by a cron tab job
>   called core_email_queue_clean_up, that's defined inside the
>   app/code/core/Mage/Core/etc/config.xml config file. The code that
>   performs the cleaning is defined on the removeSentMessages function in
>   the Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Queue class:
>
> ```
> /**
>  * Remove already sent messages
>  *
>  * @return Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Email_Queue
>  */
> public function removeSentMessages()
> {
>     $this->_getWriteAdapter()->delete($this->getMainTable(), 'processed_at IS NOT NULL');
>     return $this;
> }
> ```

I do not have this code in that location. Could this be the issue?  Any help in this matter would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

First question is: are they sending out both emails at the exact same time?
Or is one arriving later?

Next, go into core_email_queue and sort by process_at. If there are entries in there that are more then a day old. It is not being cleaned out by your cron.

So go into your core_email_queue_recipients table and search for an email address that sent twice. So in phpmyadmin click the search tab while in that table view, and enter in a@a.com (whatever email you know sent twice). Does this bring up more then one entry? Make note of the message_id for those records.

Then go into core_email_queue and search for the message_id of the previous results. If there are duplicate emails to the same recipient, then that is why it is sending twice.

Let me know how that goes, and I can help from there.

Comment: It sends 3 emails at the exact same time to two different customers. 

Customer A - Sales email 1. Order ID on Message Title 001 - Order ID in Receipt 001

Customer B - Sales email 2. Order ID on Message Title 001 - Order ID in Receipt 002

Customer B - Sales email 3. Order ID on Message Title 001 - Order ID in Receipt 002

Customer A is being CC'd both customer B's duplicate sales emails. Customer A gets 3 emails. 1 which is their correct order and 2 more because they are being CC'd to customer B's duplicates.

Comment: It happens every 4 to 8 orders or so. core_email_queue_recipients and core_email_queue is empty and gets cleared after every order.

Comment: Do you have any extensions installed? If so, what ones?
I would recommend installing this extension:
https://www.magentocommerce.com/magento-connect/aoe-scheduler.html
This will let you see all your cron jobs. It is a great tool to have. And then you can turn off  core_email_queue_clean_up Then when this happens you can look in your core_email_queue tables to see if it is putting entries that are incorrect. Let me know