# Mandrill sending order confirmation mails 2 times

Tags: magento-1.9, ce-1.9.1.0, order-email

I am facing an issue with Mandrill extension. I installed Mandrill extension because order confirmation mails were going to spam. That issue is resolved but now order confirmation mails coming 2 times. What can be the issue?

I have disabled SMTPPro extension also but if I enable SMTPPro extension and disable Mandrill extension then mails are going in spam :(

I have also tried this solution (1st answer)  [New order email being sent twice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice)

Answer (score 0):

Issue was an API Key. API Key generated to use in one website, was also used in another website & so when that API was getting triggered, then 2 mails where coming. API Key changed & error gone :)