# order confirmation email send twice for customer

Tags: magento2, email, confirmation

When placing an order the customer receives two duplicate confirmation emails.

I found this solution: 
[New order email being sent twice](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/53961/new-order-email-being-sent-twice/87299#87299)
but I can't find anything in the database !!

I don't know what may be causing the problem or how to fix it. HELP!

Magento ver. 2.2.11

Comment: Did you ever find the solution @AnaMagento?  I have the same problem and after trying all solutions on the same question you found I still haven't solved this. Emails are still sent twice.