# Order confirmation email send to wierd email adresses

Tags: email, order-confirmation

Magento is sending the order confirmation mail to my store email but also to a gmail a hotmail and other email address.

I also receive the confirmation mail 2 times.

How do I resolve this issue?

Comment: [Magento order confirmation is sent to all customers](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/72755/magento-order-confirmation-is-sent-to-all-customers/73040#73040) is the answer.

Comment: The confirmation emails are those just for when you place an order? If so then it's because 1x for being the customer and 1x for being the store owner.

Answer (score 2):

To resolve this you need to check a few places. What happens most of the time is that a developer while testing will add his or her email to ensure that the checkout process is working properly but they often forget to remove themselves once the project is done.

From the Admin Panel:

**STEP 1**

- Go to System -> Configuration
- Under "General" select -> "Store Email Addresses"
- Verify the email addresses and adjust as nessary
- Check for additional store views (IMPORTANT)

**STEP 2**

- Go to System -> Configuration
- Under "Sales" select -> "Sales Emails"
- Check the "New Order Confirmation Email Sender" (Corresponding to STEP 1)
- Check the field "Send Order Email Copy To" for additional email addresses.
- Check for additional store views (IMPORTANT)

If the addresses are not obvious, they are most likely buried in additional store views for the above instructions.

Please write back in the comments bellow this post if this does not resolve your issue.