# Order emails cronjob Magento 1.9.0.1

Tags: magento-1.9, cron

As I understand it, starting from 1.9, Magento is sending order confirmations via cronjobs.

We're having some problems regarding this though. Our cronjobs is working just fine - I've tested them through AOE Scheduler - but the order emails isn't in the cron schedule.

They are, ofcourse, enabled and everything.

What could be the issue here? And is there some way to disable this behavior and send the order confirmations right away if no one has an idea of what is causing the cronjob problems.

Thanks and have a great day!

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46063/magento-1-9-1-email-queue-not-working-buggy-how-to-troubleshoot-and-what-is-co/51616#51616

Answer (score 1):

All orders that must by sent is in **core_email_queue** table.

```
SELECT * FROM `core_email_queue` WHERE `entity_type` = 'order'
```

Shows all Orders that must by sent. Check is column **processed_at** have date. If colum don't have date - cron is not starting or if have date that means that email service is not working well.

Maybe your php_cli not have permission to send email: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10010433/php-send-email-by-cli

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know and can tell, the order email cronjob is only starting in Magento 1.9.1.0 and since you are using an older version (1.9.0.1) you will not have it ;)

If no emails are sent, this is more likely to be a problem with your mail server

Also see the release notes:
http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ce19-later-release-notes

Comment: Great, I can rule out that problem then!

The other emails are sending just fine (invoices f.x) - wouldn't those have problems too, if it were our mail server?