# Magento 1.9.4.1 Invoice emails are sent before the order confirmation emails are sent

Tags: magento-1.9, email, invoice, order-email

After placing an order in Magento 1.9.4.1, an order receives the status of 'Processing'. The funny thing is that Invoice emails are sent immediately, and a couple fo minutes later, the order confirmation emails are sent.

Both (order confirmations emails and order emails) are enabled. Has anyone had experienced these issues before? It should be the other way around (so order confirmation emails first, and then the invoice emails)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Later versions of magento 1 introduced an email queue mechanism. Caused more problems that it solved in my opinion.

[Order emails cronjob Magento 1.9.0.1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/56273/order-emails-cronjob-magento-1-9-0-1)

But that's why