# How do I set up my cronjob?

Tags: cron, windows

My e-mail system doesn't work. I got no e-mails when im buying products or if I'm getting messages via contact form. I guess my cronjob doesn't work 
I read that Scheduler would be a nice extension so I installed it. I got the following message : `No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly.`So how do I do this? I'm using xampp on a windows pc.
My cron settings:

[image]

I never edit the cron.sh file

Comment: Cron Job need the server to involve. You should setup the cronjob / crontab on your server to make it work.  See http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron

Comment: For windows http://stackoverflow.com/questions/132971/what-is-the-windows-version-of-cron

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Either the file `cron.sh` or `cron.php` must be executed periodically by the server's system cron in order to trigger Magento's internal cron.

It's a two step process.

You can simulate having the cron job set up by calling `cron.php` from a web browser, wget or curl periodically to see if Magento is internally setup properly, for Magento cron jobs to fully run, you must have the crontab entry set up either through cPanel or in your OS configurations.

Windows requires a scheduler entry since you're using that. It will need to call the command line version of the php interpreter to execute the full path `cron.php` file as in `c:\wherever\you\have\magento root\cron.php`

Scheduler is reporting no heartbeat found because this periodic invoking of cron.php isn't happening.

Comment: Yeah this works for me now. "I'm getting Scheduler is working" For everyone who is having the same problem : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9894804/use-php-to-set-cron-jobs-in-windows solution 3 is working fine. But my email traffic still doesn't work

Comment: e-mail on 1.9.x.x where they converted to queued transactional email instead of immediate send has its own issues. [One such question is here.](http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46063/magento-1-9-1-email-queue-not-working-buggy-how-to-troubleshoot-and-what-is-co) You might try searching for more questions about it as it has been a pain to many.

Comment: Is possible run cron job in localhost in wamp