# Why are Sales & General emails are not being received on my website?

Tags: magento-1.9, email, smtp

Emails on my site are not working despite having SMTP Pro installed. The Self-Test works perfectly fine but once I test the contact form or anything else they are not coming through to the recipient. My mail server is with Office 365 and requires all SMTP info for it to allow the email.

Why do the emails not work despite having SMTP Pro installed and the self test working?

Any help is much appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

This may be moot if you already have cron jobs set up, but that is what it sounds like.

If you are not sure, you can find out by checking the database:

```
select * from core_email_queue;
```

That should show the emails that are yet to be sent, and if they date back farther than an hour, it is almost definitely the cron that you are missing (most cron jobs are set up to send emails every 5-15 minutes).

*There is also an answer about testing the cron jobs [HERE](https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/74933/33071)*

If it turns out that crons are the problem, you can set it to run in CLI by using the following command:

```
crontab -e
```

And when the cron file opens, add this:

```
*/5 * * * * sh /path-to-magento/cron.sh
```

Depending on your server, it will tell you, but the 5 in this case is 5 minutes and each asterisk represents a longer period of time, in this order:  minutes, hours, day of the month, month, and day of the week.

*Magento DevDocs has additional information [HERE](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installing_install.html#install-cron)*

Once that is set up correctly (which you can verify by testing with the link above) you will just have to make sure that the settings in `Magento Admin->System->Configuration->Advanced->System->Cron (Scheduled Tasks)`

*Magento User Documentation has additional information [HERE](http://docs.magento.com/m1/ce/user_guide/system-operations/cron.html)*