# CRON (AoE Scheduler) and Magento v. 1.9.2.2 not sending emails

Tags: cron, ce-1.9.2.2, email-scheduler

CRON is working fine according to the Scheduler and all mails were working fine as of monday. Yesterday I noticed that no emails were going out. Is the normal return value from `core_email_queue_send_all` supposed to be `Mage_Core_Model_Email_Quenue`?

[image: AoE Scheduler]

Nonetheless I can see transactional emails being generated in the database under `mage_core_email_queue`.

[image: table: mage_core_email_queue]

My problem being that they are not sent, either to the recipient or being delivered to the bcc.

Changes I did since monday were installing and uninstalling 2 extensions, Algolia Search and Instant Search+.

I've tried editing cron.php and have added `$isShellDisabled = true;` beneath
 `$isShellDisabled = (stripos(PHP_OS, 'win') === false) ? $isShellDisabled : true;`
and changed
`$cronPath = escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__) . '/cron.sh');` to
`$cronPath = escapeshellarg(dirname(__FILE__) . '/scheduler_cron.sh');`

Any other tricks I should try to get emails functioning again?

Or is my best bet to roll the database back a few days?

When I manually try to fire cron.php from the browser it doesn't show up in the scheduler.

Comment: What's your 'cron_schedule' table like?

Comment: Default values are set. 15/20/15/10/60/600/15 and heartbeat is set at */10 * * * *.

Mails are set at */1 * * * *

Under cron log I can see the following:
`[10-Dec-2015 11:00:15 UTC] PHP Notice:  Trying to get property of non-object in /home/u13g8j8/www/app/code/community/Wyomind/Watchlog/Model/Observer.php on line 112
[10-Dec-2015 11:00:15 UTC] PHP Warning:  Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in /home/u13g8j8/www/app/code/community/Wyomind/Watchlog/Model/Observer.php on line 112`

Comment: I'm talking about the MySQL table 'db_name'.'cron_schedule'

Comment: Sorry, `mage_cron_schedule` is filled with 125 rows. Some pending and the rest have a status of `success`. The same I can find by looking at the scheduler under `List View`

Comment: Have you tried disabling the Wyomind Watchlog? It's clearly NOT compatible with Magento 1.9.2.2

Comment: Yeah, just removed it, so it shouldn't be the reason why it stopped working.

Comment: https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/46063/magento-1-9-1-email-queue-not-working-buggy-how-to-troubleshoot-and-what-is-co/51616#51616